# "BindingSource can't be its own DataSource"

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on a C# WinForms application which reads data into DataGridViews and exports those into an Excel worksheet with Excel Interop.

Recently, there has sometimes been a strange error that hasn't (to my knowledge) happened before. During the Excel export that happens in a different thread, the error "BindingSource can't be its own DataSource" is thrown. Not everytime, only sometimes and seemingly random.

I researched this error a bit and it seems the error occurs when you try to update a DataGridView from an external thread without Invokes. The Export function receives the DataGridView as an argument (wasn't done by me and would be too much work to change everywhere) and then loops the rows and columns to get the data into the Excel. I don't update anything in the DataGridView, but maybe there is something else that causes this error.

My question is: Does someone know exactly which types of access require making an additional Invoker function to call the grid from UI instead of in the thread? For example, can I ask a `grid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value` without Invoke (using the grid that is an argument). Can I loop through columns or ask a column name with `DataGridViewColumn.Name`? A Column Index? Ask if `grid.Columns.Contains("name")`?

I need to know what I need to make thread safe in order to prevent this error from occuring. And if someone knows anything about this error that I haven't mentioned here, I would appreciate it if you could help me in this regard too. Thanks for you help.

Edit:
Code samples:

```
        //param is an object[] that contains all the parameters, 
        //including "grid", the DataGridView
        private void ExportToExcel(object param)
        {
        //declare variables, start excel, nothing relevant before this
        ...
            for (int k = 0; k < grid.Rows.Count; k++) // Zeilen durchgehen
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[k];
                if (!row.Visible)
                    continue;

                for (int j = 0; j < grid.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                   string colName = grid.Columns[i].Name;
                   if(colName == "FirstColumn")
                   {
                       //format excel cell for firstcolumn
                       ...
                       worksheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = row.Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                   }
                   ...
                }
             ...
             }
          ...
      }

      //call of excel function
      object[] params = new object[]{this.dgvGrid, other, parameters}
      Thread excelThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExportToExcel));
      excelThread.Start(params);
```

Edit2: All the interactions I do with DataGridView in this function.

```
//Retrieve:
grid.Rows[i]
row.Visible
row.Cells[column.Name].Value
grid.Columns.Count
grid.Columns.Contains(name)
column.DataPropertyName
cell.ValueType
column.HeaderText
```

I thoroughly scanned the whole function. In no place is there an assignment to a DataGridView-related object. In only retrieve the above things. The cell values are stored in local variables and manipulated ( `object val = grid.Cells[j].Value; val = val.ToString() + "%";`)

Comment: Could you please ease the understanding/helping process by writing a relevant portion of your code, rather than relying on confusing abstract statements (which come from the assumption that you did everything as you are describing it without making any error what might not even be the case)?

Comment: I think this question can be at least 2 questions. **When I need to Invoke?** and **What is "BindingSource can't be its own DataSource" and Why I receive it?** and it's better to provide some simple codes to reproduce the problem or post some relevant parts of your code :)

Comment: @varocarbas I added code samples.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, maybe it could be 2 questions. But the main question is: How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Just retrieving values/properties from a `DataGridView` (or any other control) is not a problem. The problem (and what you error seems to indicate) is editing that control. Some part of your code is editing the `DataGridView` but you haven't included it in the sample above.

Comment: @varocarbas I edited my question to show what interaction my function has with datagridview. I thoroughly scanned the function and the visible code doesn't update anything.

Comment: Note that with `DataGridViewRow row = grid.Rows[k];`, you are converting `row` into part of the DataGridView. That is: any modification done in `row` would be reflected in the `DataGridView` (and thus would trigger an error). Things like that might be a bit more difficult to be tracked. Anyway... by looking at your code everything is right; there has to be something wrong in what you are not showing. On the other hand, note that SO (or I) is not here to custom-fix your problems for you. The answer to your question is: you can retrieve all the information without any problem.

Comment: @varocarbas Thanks, I'm aware that changes in row are also part of the DataGridView. If retrieving the data is not the problem, then the problem has to be something else (maybe something that's not related to updating the DataGridView, but still causes this error). Maybe I'll find out something.